# Shell / Makefile Linker

Tags: c++, c, xcode, makefile, avr

I have downloaded the makefile and I'm running it with C/C++ code in xcode.

It works and output the information (in console mode), but when I'm doing app (with GUI) it says:

```
**make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory

make: *** [main.o] Error 1**
```

I'm running it like this:

```
snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "make -C \"%s/System/\" flash", path);
```

etc.. but the compiler dosen't generate / export the (.o) files, so the linker fails to find them.

[The makefile is](http://electrons.psychogenic.com/articles/Makefile.tpl):

```
#########  AVR Project Makefile Template   #########
######                                        ######
######    Copyright (C) 2003-2005,Pat Deegan, ######
######            Psychogenic Inc             ######
######          All Rights Reserved           ######
######                                        ######
###### You are free to use this code as part  ######
###### of your own applications provided      ######
###### you keep this copyright notice intact  ######
###### and acknowledge its authorship with    ######
###### the words:                             ######
######                                        ######
###### "Contains software by Pat Deegan of    ######
###### Psychogenic Inc (www.psychogenic.com)" ######
######                                        ######
###### If you use it as part of a web site    ######
###### please include a link to our site,     ######
###### http://electrons.psychogenic.com  or   ######
###### http://www.psychogenic.com             ######
######                                        ######
####################################################


##### This Makefile will make compiling Atmel AVR 
##### micro controller projects simple with Linux 
##### or other Unix workstations and the AVR-GCC 
##### tools.
#####
##### It supports C, C++ and Assembly source files.
#####
##### Customize the values as indicated below and :
##### make
##### make disasm 
##### make stats 
##### make hex
##### make writeflash
##### make gdbinit
##### or make clean
#####
##### See the http://electrons.psychogenic.com/ 
##### website for detailed instructions


####################################################
#####                                          #####
#####              Configuration               #####
#####                                          #####
##### Customize the values in this section for #####
##### your project. MCU, PROJECTNAME and       #####
##### PRJSRC must be setup for all projects,   #####
##### the remaining variables are only         #####
##### relevant to those needing additional     #####
##### include dirs or libraries and those      #####
##### who wish to use the avrdude programmer   #####
#####                                          #####
##### See http://electrons.psychogenic.com/    #####
##### for further details.                     #####
#####                                          #####
####################################################


#####         Target Specific Details          #####
#####     Customize these for your project     #####

# Name of target controller 
# (e.g. 'at90s8515', see the available avr-gcc mmcu 
# options for possible values)
MCU=atmega8

# id to use with programmer
# default: PROGRAMMER_MCU=$(MCU)
# In case the programer used, e.g avrdude, doesn't
# accept the same MCU name as avr-gcc (for example
# for ATmega8s, avr-gcc expects 'atmega8' and 
# avrdude requires 'm8')
PROGRAMMER_MCU=m8

# Name of our project
# (use a single word, e.g. 'myproject')
PROJECTNAME=myproject

# Source files
# List C/C++/Assembly source files:
# (list all files to compile, e.g. 'a.c b.cpp as.S'):
# Use .cc, .cpp or .C suffix for C++ files, use .S 
# (NOT .s !!!) for assembly source code files.
PRJSRC=main.c myclass.cpp lowlevelstuff.S

# additional includes (e.g. -I/path/to/mydir)
INC=-I/path/to/include

# libraries to link in (e.g. -lmylib)
LIBS=

# Optimization level, 
# use s (size opt), 1, 2, 3 or 0 (off)
OPTLEVEL=s


#####      AVR Dude 'writeflash' options       #####
#####  If you are using the avrdude program
#####  (http://www.bsdhome.com/avrdude/) to write
#####  to the MCU, you can set the following config
#####  options and use 'make writeflash' to program
#####  the device.


# programmer id--check the avrdude for complete list
# of available opts.  These should include stk500,
# avr910, avrisp, bsd, pony and more.  Set this to
# one of the valid "-c PROGRAMMER-ID" values 
# described in the avrdude info page.
# 
AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMERID=stk500

# port--serial or parallel port to which your 
# hardware programmer is attached
#
AVRDUDE_PORT=/dev/ttyS1


####################################################
#####                Config Done               #####
#####                                          #####
##### You shouldn't need to edit anything      #####
##### below to use the makefile but may wish   #####
##### to override a few of the flags           #####
##### nonetheless                              #####
#####                                          #####
####################################################


##### Flags ####

# HEXFORMAT -- format for .hex file output
HEXFORMAT=ihex

# compiler
CFLAGS=-I. $(INC) -g -mmcu=$(MCU) -O$(OPTLEVEL) \
    -fpack-struct -fshort-enums             \
    -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char    \
    -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes               \
    -Wa,-ahlms=$(firstword                  \
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.c=.lst)))

# c++ specific flags
CPPFLAGS=-fno-exceptions               \
    -Wa,-ahlms=$(firstword         \
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.cpp=.lst))\
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.cc=.lst)) \
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.C=.lst)))

# assembler
ASMFLAGS =-I. $(INC) -mmcu=$(MCU)        \
    -x assembler-with-cpp            \
    -Wa,-gstabs,-ahlms=$(firstword   \
        $(<:.S=.lst) $(<.s=.lst))


# linker
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Map,$(TRG).map -mmcu=$(MCU) \
    -lm $(LIBS)

##### executables ####
CC=avr-gcc
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP=avr-objdump
SIZE=avr-size
AVRDUDE=avrdude
REMOVE=rm -f

##### automatic target names ####
TRG=$(PROJECTNAME).out
DUMPTRG=$(PROJECTNAME).s

HEXROMTRG=$(PROJECTNAME).hex 
HEXTRG=$(HEXROMTRG) $(PROJECTNAME).ee.hex
GDBINITFILE=gdbinit-$(PROJECTNAME)

# Define all object files.

# Start by splitting source files by type
#  C++
CPPFILES=$(filter %.cpp, $(PRJSRC))
CCFILES=$(filter %.cc, $(PRJSRC))
BIGCFILES=$(filter %.C, $(PRJSRC))
#  C
CFILES=$(filter %.c, $(PRJSRC))
#  Assembly
ASMFILES=$(filter %.S, $(PRJSRC))


# List all object files we need to create
OBJDEPS=$(CFILES:.c=.o)    \
    $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)\
    $(BIGCFILES:.C=.o) \
    $(CCFILES:.cc=.o)  \
    $(ASMFILES:.S=.o)

# Define all lst files.
LST=$(filter %.lst, $(OBJDEPS:.o=.lst))

# All the possible generated assembly 
# files (.s files)
GENASMFILES=$(filter %.s, $(OBJDEPS:.o=.s)) 


.SUFFIXES : .c .cc .cpp .C .o .out .s .S \
    .hex .ee.hex .h .hh .hpp


.PHONY: writeflash clean stats gdbinit stats

# Make targets:
# all, disasm, stats, hex, writeflash/install, clean
all: $(TRG)

disasm: $(DUMPTRG) stats

stats: $(TRG)
    $(OBJDUMP) -h $(TRG)
    $(SIZE) $(TRG) 

hex: $(HEXTRG)


writeflash: hex
    $(AVRDUDE) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMERID)   \
     -p $(PROGRAMMER_MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -e        \
     -U flash:w:$(HEXROMTRG)

install: writeflash

$(DUMPTRG): $(TRG) 
    $(OBJDUMP) -S  $< > $@


$(TRG): $(OBJDEPS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TRG) $(OBJDEPS)


#### Generating assembly ####
# asm from C
%.s: %.c
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# asm from (hand coded) asm
%.s: %.S
    $(CC) -S $(ASMFLAGS) $< > $@


# asm from C++
.cpp.s .cc.s .C.s :
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@



#### Generating object files ####
# object from C
.c.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


# object from C++ (.cc, .cpp, .C files)
.cc.o .cpp.o .C.o :
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# object from asm
.S.o :
    $(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


#### Generating hex files ####
# hex files from elf
#####  Generating a gdb initialisation file    #####
.out.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text                    \
        -j .data                       \
        -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@

.out.ee.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom                  \
        --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 \
        -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@


#####  Generating a gdb initialisation file    #####
##### Use by launching simulavr and avr-gdb:   #####
#####   avr-gdb -x gdbinit-myproject           #####
gdbinit: $(GDBINITFILE)

$(GDBINITFILE): $(TRG)
    @echo "file $(TRG)" > $(GDBINITFILE)

    @echo "target remote localhost:1212" \
                        >> $(GDBINITFILE)

    @echo "load"        >> $(GDBINITFILE) 
    @echo "break main"  >> $(GDBINITFILE)
    @echo "continue"    >> $(GDBINITFILE)
    @echo
    @echo "Use 'avr-gdb -x $(GDBINITFILE)'"


#### Cleanup ####
clean:
    $(REMOVE) $(TRG) $(TRG).map $(DUMPTRG)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDEPS)
    $(REMOVE) $(LST) $(GDBINITFILE)
    $(REMOVE) $(GENASMFILES)
    $(REMOVE) $(HEXTRG)



#####                    EOF                   #####
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error messages like

```
avr-gcc: No such file or directory
```

Indicate 1 of several things

1. the executable `avr-gcc` is not installed (properly)
2. and/or the PATH env var does not include the directory that holds the executable
3. the makefile was called incorrectly.
4. Others

Here are some things to try

When you say "downloaded the makefile", is that all you downloaded, or did you download a complete package (avr?) If just the makefile, you have to download the whole software package first before you can continue.

Many software packages rely on set-up information being captured automatically or passed in as env-vars to running the make file.

Look through the .txt (sometimes .doc) files that come with the software distribution. Look for README or INSTALL. You might find that you need to run a simple set of commands to setup the environment. Very often

```
./configure
make
make install
```

is all you need.

If there are no directions like that with your package, then you need to discover where your avr-gcc is located and add that to the PATH, i.e.

```
 find / -name 'avr-gcc*'
```

Take the path returned by, strip off the ending `/avr-gcc` and add it to your PATH, i.e.

```
 PATH="${PATH}:/path/to/avr-gcc-subdir"
 export PATH
 make
```

If this doesn't work, please edit your question to include a URL to the source code for this package.

Comment: The problem is, it work if i write the code in console mode, bot dosent when i use gui: i'm running it like that: snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "make -C \"%s/System/\" flash", path); etc.. but the compiler dosent generate / export  the (.o) files.. so the linker fails to find them

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information. Also, is 'configure' part of this system and did you run it? If you're still stuck at 'avr-gcc: No such file or directory' then see the first 3 of my list, one of those is the problem, you need to find out how to get your GUI to accept setting PATH etc. You'll get better help on your project if  you learn to use the right tags, I'm thinking other xcode users have probably run into this. good luck.