# C - C ++ Embed Makefile inside program

Tags: c++, c, xcode, makefile

I'm trying to embed this 'Makefile' inside my program, so I figured out how, but i'm facing a little problem. My code works if i program this in command line tool in xcode, but if i choose to program it as application using the SDL library, the compiler dosent generate or export the (.o) files.. and the linker fails to find them

The error i'm getting is: **make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory
make:**  [main.o] Error 1*

by right-clicking on the .app and choosing View Package Contents, the executable file which is inside works, but the .app dosent.

and my code is:

```
char cmd[1040];
char cwd[1024];
char path[1024];
char path2[1024];
int status;
FILE *fp;

char *path = NULL;
    size_t sizes;
    path = getcwd(path, sizes);
    cout << path << endl;



    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
    {
        snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "make -C \"%s\" flash", path);

        // i = system(cmd);


        /* Open the command for reading. */

        fp = popen(cmd, "r");

        if (fp == NULL) {

            cout << ("Failed to run command\n" );


        }


        /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */ //  So we can use it later

        while (fgets(path2, sizeof(path2)-1, fp) != NULL) {

            printf("Info: %s\n", path2);
        }

        /* close */

        status = pclose(fp);


    }
```

- Compiler for Mac

http://www.obdev.at/products/crosspack/index.html

[The makefile is](http://electrons.psychogenic.com/articles/Makefile.tpl):

```
#########  AVR Project Makefile Template   #########
######                                        ######
######    Copyright (C) 2003-2005,Pat Deegan, ######
######            Psychogenic Inc             ######
######          All Rights Reserved           ######
######                                        ######
###### You are free to use this code as part  ######
###### of your own applications provided      ######
###### you keep this copyright notice intact  ######
###### and acknowledge its authorship with    ######
###### the words:                             ######
######                                        ######
###### "Contains software by Pat Deegan of    ######
###### Psychogenic Inc (www.psychogenic.com)" ######
######                                        ######
###### If you use it as part of a web site    ######
###### please include a link to our site,     ######
###### http://electrons.psychogenic.com  or   ######
###### http://www.psychogenic.com             ######
######                                        ######
####################################################


##### This Makefile will make compiling Atmel AVR 
##### micro controller projects simple with Linux 
##### or other Unix workstations and the AVR-GCC 
##### tools.
#####
##### It supports C, C++ and Assembly source files.
#####
##### Customize the values as indicated below and :
##### make
##### make disasm 
##### make stats 
##### make hex
##### make writeflash
##### make gdbinit
##### or make clean
#####
##### See the http://electrons.psychogenic.com/ 
##### website for detailed instructions


####################################################
#####                                          #####
#####              Configuration               #####
#####                                          #####
##### Customize the values in this section for #####
##### your project. MCU, PROJECTNAME and       #####
##### PRJSRC must be setup for all projects,   #####
##### the remaining variables are only         #####
##### relevant to those needing additional     #####
##### include dirs or libraries and those      #####
##### who wish to use the avrdude programmer   #####
#####                                          #####
##### See http://electrons.psychogenic.com/    #####
##### for further details.                     #####
#####                                          #####
####################################################


#####         Target Specific Details          #####
#####     Customize these for your project     #####

# Name of target controller 
# (e.g. 'at90s8515', see the available avr-gcc mmcu 
# options for possible values)
MCU=atmega8

# id to use with programmer
# default: PROGRAMMER_MCU=$(MCU)
# In case the programer used, e.g avrdude, doesn't
# accept the same MCU name as avr-gcc (for example
# for ATmega8s, avr-gcc expects 'atmega8' and 
# avrdude requires 'm8')
PROGRAMMER_MCU=m8

# Name of our project
# (use a single word, e.g. 'myproject')
PROJECTNAME=myproject

# Source files
# List C/C++/Assembly source files:
# (list all files to compile, e.g. 'a.c b.cpp as.S'):
# Use .cc, .cpp or .C suffix for C++ files, use .S 
# (NOT .s !!!) for assembly source code files.
PRJSRC=main.c myclass.cpp lowlevelstuff.S

# additional includes (e.g. -I/path/to/mydir)
INC=-I/path/to/include

# libraries to link in (e.g. -lmylib)
LIBS=

# Optimization level, 
# use s (size opt), 1, 2, 3 or 0 (off)
OPTLEVEL=s


#####      AVR Dude 'writeflash' options       #####
#####  If you are using the avrdude program
#####  (http://www.bsdhome.com/avrdude/) to write
#####  to the MCU, you can set the following config
#####  options and use 'make writeflash' to program
#####  the device.


# programmer id--check the avrdude for complete list
# of available opts.  These should include stk500,
# avr910, avrisp, bsd, pony and more.  Set this to
# one of the valid "-c PROGRAMMER-ID" values 
# described in the avrdude info page.
# 
AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMERID=stk500

# port--serial or parallel port to which your 
# hardware programmer is attached
#
AVRDUDE_PORT=/dev/ttyS1


####################################################
#####                Config Done               #####
#####                                          #####
##### You shouldn't need to edit anything      #####
##### below to use the makefile but may wish   #####
##### to override a few of the flags           #####
##### nonetheless                              #####
#####                                          #####
####################################################


##### Flags ####

# HEXFORMAT -- format for .hex file output
HEXFORMAT=ihex

# compiler
CFLAGS=-I. $(INC) -g -mmcu=$(MCU) -O$(OPTLEVEL) \
    -fpack-struct -fshort-enums             \
    -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char    \
    -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes               \
    -Wa,-ahlms=$(firstword                  \
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.c=.lst)))

# c++ specific flags
CPPFLAGS=-fno-exceptions               \
    -Wa,-ahlms=$(firstword         \
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.cpp=.lst))\
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.cc=.lst)) \
    $(filter %.lst, $(<:.C=.lst)))

# assembler
ASMFLAGS =-I. $(INC) -mmcu=$(MCU)        \
    -x assembler-with-cpp            \
    -Wa,-gstabs,-ahlms=$(firstword   \
        $(<:.S=.lst) $(<.s=.lst))


# linker
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Map,$(TRG).map -mmcu=$(MCU) \
    -lm $(LIBS)

##### executables ####
CC=avr-gcc
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP=avr-objdump
SIZE=avr-size
AVRDUDE=avrdude
REMOVE=rm -f

##### automatic target names ####
TRG=$(PROJECTNAME).out
DUMPTRG=$(PROJECTNAME).s

HEXROMTRG=$(PROJECTNAME).hex 
HEXTRG=$(HEXROMTRG) $(PROJECTNAME).ee.hex
GDBINITFILE=gdbinit-$(PROJECTNAME)

# Define all object files.

# Start by splitting source files by type
#  C++
CPPFILES=$(filter %.cpp, $(PRJSRC))
CCFILES=$(filter %.cc, $(PRJSRC))
BIGCFILES=$(filter %.C, $(PRJSRC))
#  C
CFILES=$(filter %.c, $(PRJSRC))
#  Assembly
ASMFILES=$(filter %.S, $(PRJSRC))


# List all object files we need to create
OBJDEPS=$(CFILES:.c=.o)    \
    $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)\
    $(BIGCFILES:.C=.o) \
    $(CCFILES:.cc=.o)  \
    $(ASMFILES:.S=.o)

# Define all lst files.
LST=$(filter %.lst, $(OBJDEPS:.o=.lst))

# All the possible generated assembly 
# files (.s files)
GENASMFILES=$(filter %.s, $(OBJDEPS:.o=.s)) 


.SUFFIXES : .c .cc .cpp .C .o .out .s .S \
    .hex .ee.hex .h .hh .hpp


.PHONY: writeflash clean stats gdbinit stats

# Make targets:
# all, disasm, stats, hex, writeflash/install, clean
all: $(TRG)

disasm: $(DUMPTRG) stats

stats: $(TRG)
    $(OBJDUMP) -h $(TRG)
    $(SIZE) $(TRG) 

hex: $(HEXTRG)


writeflash: hex
    $(AVRDUDE) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMERID)   \
     -p $(PROGRAMMER_MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -e        \
     -U flash:w:$(HEXROMTRG)

install: writeflash

$(DUMPTRG): $(TRG) 
    $(OBJDUMP) -S  $< > $@


$(TRG): $(OBJDEPS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TRG) $(OBJDEPS)


#### Generating assembly ####
# asm from C
%.s: %.c
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# asm from (hand coded) asm
%.s: %.S
    $(CC) -S $(ASMFLAGS) $< > $@


# asm from C++
.cpp.s .cc.s .C.s :
    $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@



#### Generating object files ####
# object from C
.c.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


# object from C++ (.cc, .cpp, .C files)
.cc.o .cpp.o .C.o :
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# object from asm
.S.o :
    $(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


#### Generating hex files ####
# hex files from elf
#####  Generating a gdb initialisation file    #####
.out.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text                    \
        -j .data                       \
        -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@

.out.ee.hex:
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom                  \
        --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 \
        -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@


#####  Generating a gdb initialisation file    #####
##### Use by launching simulavr and avr-gdb:   #####
#####   avr-gdb -x gdbinit-myproject           #####
gdbinit: $(GDBINITFILE)

$(GDBINITFILE): $(TRG)
    @echo "file $(TRG)" > $(GDBINITFILE)

    @echo "target remote localhost:1212" \
                        >> $(GDBINITFILE)

    @echo "load"        >> $(GDBINITFILE) 
    @echo "break main"  >> $(GDBINITFILE)
    @echo "continue"    >> $(GDBINITFILE)
    @echo
    @echo "Use 'avr-gdb -x $(GDBINITFILE)'"


#### Cleanup ####
clean:
    $(REMOVE) $(TRG) $(TRG).map $(DUMPTRG)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDEPS)
    $(REMOVE) $(LST) $(GDBINITFILE)
    $(REMOVE) $(GENASMFILES)
    $(REMOVE) $(HEXTRG)



#####                    EOF                   #####
```

Comment: Where in this code is the C++, as promised by your taggings?

Comment: The makefile supports C, C++, but i was referring to any solution which use C or C++

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages. Proper C code is entirely different from proper C++ code (see alone RAII and generic code). If you can afford a C++ compiler, then why not ditch C entirely?

Comment: Also: Please don't insert multiple paragraphs per phrase. Or did you copy and paste your post from another site? In any case, I've removed many superfluous paragraphs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593611/shell-makefile-linker

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to debug that kind of bugs is to have some way to pass some additional flags to `make` like e.g.

```
    const char *makeflags = getenv("MYMAKEFLAGS");
    if (makeflags) 
       snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "make -C \"%s\" %s flash", path, makeflags);
    else
       snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "make -C \"%s\" flash", path);
```

Then you (assuming your `make` is the GNU make) could debug your thing by setting the environment variable

```
    export MYMAKEFLAGS=--debug=b
```

And I would use the `patsubst`  GNU make function to compute your OBJDEPS which should really be OBJFILES, e.g.

```
OBJFILES= \
       $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(CCFILES)) \
       $(patsubst %c, %.o, $(CFILES)) 
#etc
```

Comment: But sir, how do i implant " export MYMAKEFLAGS=--debug=b " ?? inside my source?

Comment: You don't put that in your source code. You just type that in the terminal, before running your executable which do the `make`

Comment: Well, Basile, I add the c/c++ code, changed OBJDEPS to OBJFILES in the makefile, typed:  export MYMAKEFLAGS=--debug=b in ther terminal, and run the debug in xcode, but nothing worked , it says:  make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory make: [main.o] Error 1

Comment: Run your program in the same terminal where you type the `export` command. Ensure that `avr-gcc` is inside your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: by right-clicking on the .app and choosing View Package Contents, the executable file which is inside works, but the .app dosent...